# Get WordPress Attachment PowerPoint URL in Post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to show the PPT file in this frame in WordPress post.

```
<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=<?php echo $attachment_url ?>" width="100%" height="500px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have placed this loop in post.php. But is not working.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment', // Retrieve attachments
    'post_mime_type' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', // Filter by MIME type for PPT files
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all attachments
);

$attachments = new WP_Query($args);

if ($attachments->have_posts()) :
    while ($attachments->have_posts()) : $attachments->the_post();
        $attachment_id = get_the_ID();
        $attachment_title = get_the_title();
        $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);


    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore the original post data
?>`
```

Someone please help us in correcting this code.

Comment: Not working how, exactly. Please describe the _specific_ error or unexpected behaviour you're experiencing, and what you've done to debug it so far. See also [ask]. We cannot just guess what might be the issue, we need some useful information.

Comment: Not working, it means that the URL of the .ppt file attached in the post is not get.

Comment: So does the iframe code contain the link you expected, or something else? What does the rendered html look like? Did the query return any rows? Does the url look right? Any errors in the browser console? Any php errors? That's the sort of information we need. Have you actually attempted to do any debugging? We can't tell much from just staring the code, it basically looks ok. You need to do some meaningful investigation